# How can I grab data from this web site?

Tags: web-scraping, windows-10, read-data, screen-grab, data-capture

There is a site here (http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=46741025610365786#), that each field of this table(specified by yellow squares) shows information about one specific day. What I need to do is to read only `حجم` row of each field(I mean what I specified by red squares in the following photos(You should go to the tab i mentioned in first photo, to see the second photo)):

[image]
[image]

And write them(store in my computer) in a text file like this:

```
6.832 M (14%) , 40.475 M (85%), 248,000 (0%), 47.059 M (99%)
605,000 (3%), 15.277 M (96%), 478,714 (3%), 15.404 M (96%)
8.102 M (42%), 10.751 M (57%), 9.599 M (50%), 9.253 M (49%)
215,937 (2%), 9.417 M (97%), 1.115 M (11%), 8.518 M (88%)
3.351 M (15%), 18.284 M (84%), 5.987 M (27%), 15.647 M (72%)
```

But I don't know is it possible or not? If so, how can I do that in simplest way?(I use Windows10)

> EDIT:
>   I did the step 3 successfully, and ran `node extract.js` command in step 4. I got this result:

```
[ 'حجم, 47.059 M (99%), 248,000 (0%), 40.475 M (85%), 6.832 M (14%)',
  'حجم, 15.404 M (96%), 478,714 (3%), 15.277 M (96%), 605,000 (3%)',
  'حجم, 9.253 M (49%), 9.599 M (50%), 10.751 M (57%), 8.102 M (42%)',
  'حجم, 8.518 M (88%), 1.115 M (11%), 9.417 M (97%), 215,937 (2%)',
  'حجم, 15.647 M (72%), 5.987 M (27%), 18.284 M (84%), 3.351 M (15%)',
  'حجم, 21.848 M (93%), 1.501 M (6%), 21.648 M (92%), 1.701 M (7%)',
  'حجم, 30.845 M (95%), 1.3 M (4%), 30.663 M (95%), 1.482 M (4%)',
  'حجم, 9.914 M (64%), 5.474 M (35%), 9.938 M (64%), 5.45 M (35%)',
  'حجم, 10.775 M (97%), 250,000 (2%), 10.995 M (99%), 30,000 (0%)',
  'حجم, 21.328 M (91%), 2.027 M (8%), 22.315 M (95%), 1.04 M (4%)',
  'حجم, 19.588 M (92%), 1.54 M (7%), 21.048 M (99%), 80,000 (0%)',
  'حجم, 12.554 M (96%), 418,000 (3%), 11.504 M (88%), 1.468 M (11%)',
  'حجم, 14.98 M (92%), 1.299 M (7%), 16.135 M (99%), 144,008 (0%)',
  'حجم, 10.878 M (95%), 502,040 (4%), 11.378 M (99%), 2,040 (0%)',
  'حجم, 10.012 M (97%), 275,000 (2%), 10.287 M (100%), 0 (0%)',
  'حجم, 11.992 M (95%), 500,000 (4%), 11.707 M (93%), 785,244 (6%)',
  'حجم, 16.492 M (95%), 820,000 (4%), 17.056 M (98%), 256,241 (1%)',
  'حجم, 19.639 M (98%), 378,384 (1%), 20.017 M (100%), 0 (0%)',
  'حجم, 13.781 M (95%), 639,609 (4%), 14.161 M (98%), 260,000 (1%)',
  'حجم, 31.797 M (99%), 300,507 (0%), 26.089 M (81%), 6.009 M (18%)',
  'حجم, 18.159 M (99%), 30,391 (0%), 15.914 M (87%), 2.275 M (12%)',
  'حجم, 21.271 M (95%), 1.01 M (4%), 21.501 M (96%), 780,000 (3%)',
  'حجم, 17.322 M (62%), 10.615 M (37%), 19.437 M (69%), 8.5 M (30%)',
  'حجم, 37.817 M (97%), 1.03 M (2%), 34.125 M (87%), 4.722 M (12%)',
  'حجم, 55.396 M (99%), 211,000 (0%), 52.507 M (94%), 3.1 M (5%)',
  'حجم, 23.141 M (98%), 420,000 (1%), 23.461 M (99%), 100,000 (0%)',
  'حجم, 46.215 M (82%), 9.919 M (17%), 49.764 M (88%), 6.371 M (11%)',
  'حجم, 1.26 M (100%), 0 (0%), 1.26 M (100%), 0 (0%)',
  'حجم, 35.89 M (99%), 251,000 (0%), 35.921 M (99%), 220,000 (0%)',
  'حجم, 48.509 M (88%), 6.349 M (11%), 54.052 M (98%), 806,362 (1%)',
  'حجم, 41.018 M (91%), 4.006 M (8%), 41.564 M (92%), 3.46 M (7%)',
  'حجم, 40.02 M (99%), 100,000 (0%), 39.22 M (97%), 900,000 (2%)',
  'حجم, 36.974 M (99%), 30,000 (0%), 36.549 M (98%), 455,500 (1%)',
  'حجم, 35.739 M (99%), 230,000 (0%), 33.104 M (92%), 2.866 M (7%)',
  'حجم, 19.627 M (100%), 0 (0%), 18.877 M (96%), 750,000 (3%)',
  'حجم, 19.603 M (81%), 4.379 M (18%), 23.982 M (100%), 0 (0%)',
  'حجم, 10.186 M (97%), 250,000 (2%), 10.436 M (100%), 0 (0%)',
  'حجم, 15.414 M (98%), 250,500 (1%), 15.465 M (98%), 200,000 (1%)',
  'حجم, 21.571 M (97%), 665,000 (2%), 22.236 M (100%), 0 (0%)',
  'حجم, 15.537 M (98%), 250,000 (1%), 15.787 M (100%), 0 (0%)',
  'حجم, 21.422 M (98%), 221,004 (1%), 21.243 M (98%), 400,000 (1%)',
  'حجم, 30.662 M (92%), 2.375 M (7%), 33.036 M (100%), 0 (0%)',
  'حجم, 39.287 M (98%), 455,000 (1%), 39.742 M (100%), 0 (0%)',
  'حجم, 53.141 M (89%), 6.11 M (10%), 59.131 M (99%), 120,000 (0%)',
  'حجم, 23.587 M (98%), 255,000 (1%), 23.842 M (100%), 0 (0%)',
  'حجم, 17.043 M (98%), 255,000 (1%), 17.298 M (100%), 0 (0%)',
  'حجم, 33.51 M (96%), 1.25 M (3%), 34.75 M (99%), 10,000 (0%)',
  'حجم, 36.408 M (99%), 15,000 (0%), 28.248 M (77%), 8.175 M (22%)',
  'حجم, 32.367 M (98%), 480,000 (1%), 31.535 M (96%), 1.312 M (3%)',
  'حجم, 54.773 M (95%), 2.68 M (4%), 43.936 M (76%), 13.517 M (23%)',
  'حجم, 58.955 M (95%), 2.54 M (4%), 41.234 M (67%), 20.262 M (32%)',
  'حجم, 45.222 M (99%), 15,000 (0%), 40.215 M (88%), 5.023 M (11%)',
  'حجم, 43.487 M (97%), 1.225 M (2%), 43.902 M (98%), 810,008 (1%)',
  'حجم, 35.46 M (91%), 3.18 M (8%), 38.33 M (99%), 310,000 (0%)',
  'حجم, 39.42 M (99%), 90,927 (0%), 36.722 M (92%), 2.789 M (7%)',
  'حجم, 41.024 M (99%), 312,000 (0%), 35.814 M (86%), 5.522 M (13%)',
  'حجم, 32.718 M (99%), 277,978 (0%), 30.995 M (93%), 2.001 M (6%)',
  'حجم, 1.12 M (100%), 0 (0%), 1.12 M (100%), 0 (0%)',
  'حجم, 2.015 M (86%), 325,000 (13%), 2.34 M (100%), 0 (0%)',
  'حجم, 40.402 M (95%), 2.109 M (4%), 42.511 M (100%), 0 (0%)',
  'حجم, 41.726 M (86%), 6.372 M (13%), 48.098 M (100%), 0 (0%)',
  'حجم, 39.444 M (97%), 1.14 M (2%), 39.551 M (97%), 1.033 M (2%)',
  'حجم, 4.14 M (100%), 0 (0%), 3.14 M (75%), 1,000,000 (24%)',
  'حجم, 43.447 M (96%), 1.743 M (3%), 44.292 M (98%), 898,000 (1%)',
  'حجم, 56.023 M (98%), 864,338 (1%), 52.627 M (92%), 4.26 M (7%)',
  'حجم, 14.062 M (99%), 8,008 (0%), 12.055 M (85%), 2.015 M (14%)',
  'حجم, 56.557 M (84%), 10.413 M (15%), 66.47 M (99%), 500,000 (0%)',
  'حجم, 7.971 M (69%), 3.481 M (30%), 11.452 M (100%), 0 (0%)',
  'حجم, 38.85 M (86%), 5.864 M (13%), 44.494 M (99%), 220,000 (0%)',
  'حجم, 53.151 M (99%), 105,000 (0%), 51.039 M (95%), 2.217 M (4%)',
  'حجم, 51.861 M (79%), 13.352 M (20%), 64.603 M (99%), 610,000 (0%)',
  'حجم, 2.025 M (80%), 500,000 (19%), 2.525 M (100%), 0 (0%)',
  'حجم, 67.428 M (95%), 3.294 M (4%), 68.538 M (96%), 2.184 M (3%)',
  'حجم, 52.373 M (87%), 7.211 M (12%), 58.408 M (98%), 1.176 M (1%)',
  'حجم, 12.073 M (80%), 3.01 M (19%), 14.583 M (96%), 500,000 (3%)',
  'حجم, 47.369 M (99%), 424,000 (0%), 30.168 M (63%), 17.626 M (36%)',
  'حجم, 3.401 M (100%), 0 (0%), 1.039 M (30%), 2.363 M (69%)',
  'حجم, 52.213 M (99%), 247,000 (0%), 41.872 M (79%), 10.588 M (20%)',
  'حجم, 73.585 M (98%), 1.356 M (1%), 38.911 M (51%), 36.029 M (48%)',
  'حجم, 67.943 M (97%), 1.622 M (2%), 35.571 M (51%), 33.995 M (48%)',
  'حجم, 2.653 M (100%), 0 (0%), 2.003 M (75%), 650,000 (24%)',
  'حجم, 32.055 M (99%), 18,408 (0%), 24.301 M (75%), 7.772 M (24%)',
  'حجم, 16.989 M (98%), 209,000 (1%), 9.598 M (55%), 7.6 M (44%)',
  'حجم, 34.906 M (95%), 1.64 M (4%), 21.129 M (57%), 15.417 M (42%)',
  'حجم, 14.669 M (98%), 150,000 (1%), 7.852 M (52%), 6.967 M (47%)',
  'حجم, 23.542 M (98%), 289,600 (1%), 23.102 M (96%), 729,782 (3%)',
  'حجم, 27.87 M (98%), 450,000 (1%), 21.461 M (75%), 6.859 M (24%)',
  'حجم, 48.785 M (98%), 500,000 (1%), 30.683 M (62%), 18.603 M (37%)',
  'حجم, 22.839 M (93%), 1.518 M (6%), 16.242 M (66%), 8.115 M (33%)',
  'حجم, 15.683 M (96%), 631,500 (3%), 13.316 M (81%), 2.999 M (18%)',
  'حجم, 15.715 M (96%), 630,000 (3%), 15.436 M (94%), 908,399 (5%)',
  'حجم, 11.776 M (90%), 1.305 M (9%), 13.081 M (100%), 0 (0%)',
  'حجم, 12.492 M (85%), 2.057 M (14%), 14.149 M (97%), 400,000 (2%)',
  'حجم, 11.909 M (100%), 0 (0%), 11.818 M (99%), 91,008 (0%)',
  'حجم, 21.404 M (99%), 140,000 (0%), 17.8 M (82%), 3.744 M (17%)',
  'حجم, 22.115 M (89%), 2.718 M (10%), 21.969 M (88%), 2.864 M (11%)',
  'حجم, 23.146 M (97%), 637,396 (2%), 21.881 M (92%), 1.902 M (7%)',
  'حجم, 35.986 M (94%), 1.92 M (5%), 25.749 M (67%), 12.156 M (32%)',
  'حجم, 16.064 M (93%), 1.179 M (6%), 17.104 M (99%), 139,467 (0%)',
  'حجم, 19.314 M (85%), 3.284 M (14%), 22.408 M (99%), 189,500 (0%)',
  ... 84 more items ]
(node:13916) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function
    at maybeCallback (fs.js:129:9)
    at Object.writeFile (fs.js:1159:14)
    at C:\Users\m\Desktop\GetData\extract.js:21:14
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:13916) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13916) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process
```

with a non-zero exit code.

But there is no `store.txt` file!

Comment: The link you provided doesn't have the same content as you have shown in the screenshot if you provide it correct I can help. Its really simple with puppeteer.js

Comment: @SaurabhNarhe: Thank you very much for help. I edited my question and added a new photo.

Comment: try again same command with active internet connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download and install node.js & npm from here - https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm
2. Create folder anywhere in your pc, create a file extract.js in it and paste following code.

   [Code](https://gist.github.com/saurabhnarhe/f808b4ad7576e037b741a431ad2cd0ec)
3. Then open command prompt in that folder and run "npm install puppeteer"(it may take several minutes to complete)
4. Then run "node extract.js"
5. After it runs successfully you will have "store.txt" file in the same folder which contains your expected result.

Comment: Thank you very much Saurabh! As I am completely new on this, can I use puppteer in Windows10? How should I install it and where I must use the above code?

Comment: I also like to know how can I delete the word `حجم` ? I don't need that word in grabbed data.

Comment: Where should I find `store.txt` file?

Comment: Is it possible to remove parentheses with percent numbers? I mean I get rows like this `6.832 M  , 40.475 M , 248,000 , 47.059 M ` ...without parentheses and percentages.

Comment: @user3486308, I have updated the code, please replace your code with new one. I am still working for removing parentheses and percentages. I'll let you know soon.

Comment: You are great man!
Just one question: the `store.txt` file's content is something like this `47.059 M, 248,000, 40.475 M, 6.832 M, 15.404 M, 478,714, 15.277 M, 605,000, 9.253 M, 2.34 M, 0` , How can I put each 4 numbers in a line?